# Messages not appearing after creating an app for it in Django

Tags: python, django

I created an app called marketing app which customizes messages to be written on top of website page. My problem is that these messages are not showing when everything is configured and I don't know why is that

This is the model of the Marketing App

```
class MarketingMessage(models.Model):
    message = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False, null=True, blank=True)
    end = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.message[:12])
```

this is the views for the core app

```
from marketing.models import MarketingMessage

class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Item
    paginate_by = 10
    template_name = "home.html"
    marketing_message = MarketingMessage.objects.all()[0]
```

this is the template

```
{% if marketing_message %}

<div class="alert alert-light alert-top-message" role="alert"style="margin-bottom: 0px; border-radius: 0px; text-align: center;padding-top:80px">
    <div class="container">
    <h3>{{ marketing_message.message }}</h3>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    </div>
</div>
{% endif  %}
```

This is the admin.py of marketing

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import MarketingMessage
# Register your models here.


class MarketingMessageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Meta:
        model = MarketingMessage


admin.site.register(MarketingMessage, MarketingMessageAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want get data from another model, you can over ride the get context data method in view

```
class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Item
    paginate_by = 10
    template_name = "home.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['marketing_message'] = MarketingMessage.objects.all()
        return context
```

Comment: i have wrote it like this:   ` def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['marketing_message'] = MarketingMessage.objects.all()
    return context


class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Item
    paginate_by = 10
    template_name = "home.html"
    marketing_message = MarketingMessage.objects.all()[0] `  but still nothing is showing

Comment: you are right but I think the template might have something wrong with it, I am checking it